# How to display a label with click on listview

Tags: xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, label, viewmodel

I want to show a label when i click on my item in my listview.
The real problem i don't know how to link between my viewmodel and my views

I want modify my label in viewmodel but I don't know if its possible currently.

My xaml :

```
      <StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="labelperso"
           Text="{Binding newProduct}"
  IsVisible="{Binding Addproduct}"      
VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"    
    BackgroundColor="#000000"
 FontSize="20"
    Opacity="0"/>

    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" RowHeight="50" >
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
  <DataTemplate>
            <TextCell Text="{Binding CodeReferenceLibelle}" TextColor="Black"/>              
  </DataTemplate>     
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>        
    <ListView.Behaviors>
  <b:EventToCommandBehavior EventName="ItemSelected" Command="{Binding 
   SelectCommand}" Converter="{StaticResource SelectedItemConverter}"/>
</ListView.Behaviors>
```

my viewmodel :

```
  #region labelperso property
    private string _newProduct;
    public string newProduct
    {
        get { return _newProduct; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _newProduct, value); }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Addproduct property
    private bool _Addproduct;
    public bool Addproduct
    {
        get { return _Addproduct; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _Addproduct, value); }
    }
    #endregion
```

when I click on my item :

```
async Task Select()
    {
               newProduct = "Produit ajouté !";
                basketManager.AddProductSkuAsync(sku);

                newProduct = "";
 await Task.Run(() => ShowText());
 }

  //I have tried this but I can't use my label in my view
  async Task ShowText()
    {
        await labelperso.FadeTo(1);
        await Task.Delay(1000);
        await labelperso.FadeTo(0);
    }
```

Comment: Where are you detecting the item click, in ViewModel?

Comment: You will need to add a command to your vm with name SelectCommand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you want to take the label "labelperso" in VM ? you can use it in `xaml.cs` instead. 
You just need to add the event `ItemSelected` like this:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" ItemSelected="OnSelection">
```

In `xaml.cs`

```
void OnSelection(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.SelectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }
       //suppose the binding Object is Product
        Product product = (Product)e.SelectedItem;
        //labelperso.Text = "name = " + product.Name;

         labelperso.FadeTo(1);
         Task.Delay(1000);
         labelperso.FadeTo(0);
    }
```

Normally, VM are unrelated to Xaml, and we should not get labels from VM.
And we don't recommend it.But if you must, you can pass the Label in from the xaml.cs file like this:
You can define a variable in yourpage.xaml.cs:

```
public Label pageLabel;
```

and initial like this:

```
 pageLabel = labelperso;
 BindingContext = new YourViewmodel(this);
```

And in YourViewmodel.cs:

```
 public Label ss;

  public YourViewmodel(ContentPage parentPage)
    {// here HomePage is  your contentPage  name of the page`          
        ss = ((HomePage)parentPage).pageLabel;//after this you can use it 
    }
```

Comment: thx i wanted to know if it was possible to get my label in my VM ?

Comment: @Deos  Normally, VM are unrelated to Xaml, and we should not get labels from VM.I have updated my answer, you can check it.

Comment: Thx it work, I use your first advice. However I have a problem about my label. I didn't see it, I think my command in my VM is working too fast I have no time for seing my label

Comment: @Deos    Congrats, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `SelectedProduct` property to your VM.

```
private string _SelectedProduct;
public string SelectedProduct
{
    get { return _SelectedProduct; }
    set { SetProperty(ref _SelectedProduct, value); }
}
```

You can then bind your ListView's `SelectedItem` to it

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Products}" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedProduct}"
          CachingStrategy="RecycleElement" 
          RowHeight="50" >
```

You can then control the visibility of your label by binding to SelectedProduct via a "nullToVisibility" converter, or by using triggers etc.

Comment: Hello my click on my listView work, but I want to FadeTo my label like a notifying. I don't know how take the current label "labelperso" in my VM and use it.

Comment: A label is a UI component, and so should be in the view, not the viewmodel. Create it in the view and then bind its visibility to SelectedProduct like I said, or bind its content to a string in the viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use MVVM pattern rather than hacking with code behind.

Using MVVM you can add a Visible property to your viewmodel and bind the IsVisible property of the label to it.
Code will be much easy to read and maintain.